# Error with VideoCapabilities while creating web wrapper in Android

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to create native application who's will be a wrapper for HTML5 with Javascript/Typescript website. In this website, there are many videos. When I open this website in native Chrome app, then it's work, but when I open this website in my app, then it's not work because videos aren't loaded properly. Below is code and log. What's wrong with that? I tried to use traditional WebClient and WebChromeClient but it not solved this problem.

```
Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        WebView webView= new WebView(this);

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            @Override
            public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
                getWindow().setTitle(title); //Set Activity tile to page title.
            }
        });

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }
        });

        webView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.182:10000");
    }
```

And the log

```
 I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter$7>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/webkit/RenderProcessGoneDetail;
               at void com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(java.util.Map, boolean) (WebViewChromium.java:48)
               at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean) (WebView.java:-1)
               at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:-1)
               at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:-1)
    I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:-1)
               at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context) (WebView.java:-1)
               at void test.tv_cli.WebViewActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (WebViewActivity.java:58)
               at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:-1)
               at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:-1)
               at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
               at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
               at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
               at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
               at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:-1)
               at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:-1)
               at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
               at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
               at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:-1)
               at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:-1)
           Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.webkit.RenderProcessGoneDetail" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.google.android.webview-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.google.android.webview-2/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.google.android.webview-2/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
               at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
               at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
               at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
               at void com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(java.util.Map, boolean) (WebViewChromium.java:48)
               at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean) (WebView.java:-1)
               at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:-1)
               at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:-1)
               at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:-1)
               at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context) (WebView.java:-1)
               at void test.tv_cli.WebViewActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (WebViewActivity.java:58)
               at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:-1)
               at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:-1)
               at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
               at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
               at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
               at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
               at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:-1)
               at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:-1)
               at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
               at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
               at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:-1)
               at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:-1)
    I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter$3>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/webkit/SafeBrowsingResponse;
               at void com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(java.util.Map, boolean) (WebViewChromium.java:48)
               at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean) (WebView.java:-1)
               at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:-1)
               at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:-1)
               at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:-1)
               at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context) (WebView.java:-1)
               at void test.tv_cli.WebViewActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (WebViewActivity.java:58)
               at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:-1)
               at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:-1)
               at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
               at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
               at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
               at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
               at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:-1)
               at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:-1)
               at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
               at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
               at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:-1)
               at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:-1)
           Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.webkit.SafeBrowsingResponse" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.google.android.webview-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.google.android.webview-2/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.google.android.webview-2/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
               at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
               at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
               at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
               at void com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(java.util.Map, boolean) (WebViewChromium.java:48)
               at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean) (WebView.java:-1)
               at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:-1)
    I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:-1)
               at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:-1)
               at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context) (WebView.java:-1)
               at void test.tv_cli.WebViewActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (WebViewActivity.java:58)
               at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:-1)
               at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:-1)
               at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
               at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
               at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
               at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
               at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:-1)
               at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:-1)
               at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
               at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
               at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:-1)
               at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:-1)
    D/EgretLoader: EgretLoader(Context context)
    D/EgretLoader: The context is not activity
    W/cr_media: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
    E/libEGL: validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
    I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : d57aba2, Ic27b94dfce
              Build Date                       : 10/26/16
              OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.09.00.03
              Local Branch                     : 
              Remote Branch                    : 
              Remote Branch                    : 
              Reconstruct Branch               : 
    D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
    V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@3677baf
                      BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@3192bbc
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
                         Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
                         Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
                         Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 0/3 for video/mpeg2
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 0/3 for video/mpeg2
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx311
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx4
    W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
    W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/dsd
                         Unsupported mime audio/dts
    W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/32KADPCM
    W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mp4v-esdp
    I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
    D/ActivityThreadInjector: clearCachedDrawables.
    I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
    D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
    I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Refused to execute script from 'http://192.168.1.182:10000/$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/Widget.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.", source: http://192.168.1.182:10000/ (0)
    W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
    I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Refused to execute script from 'http://192.168.1.182:10000/$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/TVKeyValue.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.", source: http://192.168.1.182:10000/ (0)
    I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(12)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: Common is not defined", source: http://192.168.1.182:10000/ (12)
    W/cr_CrashFileManager: /data/user/0/test.tv_cli/cache/WebView/Crash Reports does not exist or is not a directory
    I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(2697)] "[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...", source: http://192.168.1.182:10000/bundle.js (2697)
    I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(858)] "start debug", source: http://192.168.1.182:10000/bundle.js (858)
    I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(3367)] "[WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.", source: http://192.168.1.182:10000/bundle.js (3367)
    V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@b98fe31
    I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(12560)] "100[100-0]undefined", source: http://192.168.1.182:10000/bundle.js (12560)
```

Comment: Could you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Still no solution?

Comment: if I remember correctly, this log's doesn't matter, cause problem was on website instead on android application. Probably I didn't fix it, and application works correct

Comment: Please share your design(xml) here. For me am facing same issue, am updated webview height as wrap_content to match_parent its working.Hope it is useful for you.